# How to copy partial topic data from one cluster to another

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a use case where I need to copy the data from one topic to another topic in a different cluster but I need to copy only from a given offset. What can I use for the above use case?

I have looked into mirror maker as it copies data from one cluster to another but how to mention the offset part, I am not getting that.
Is there any utility I can use?

Comment: Don't copy partial data from a topic. I would recommend you to use mirror-maker and make a fully copy of your topic. Also, users should not use offsets.

Comment: Can you expand on your use-case here? Is this a one-time operation, or are you looking to build this as a repeatable process? What's the significance of the offset from which you want to copy data?

Comment: This will be a one time operation. We will be bringing down the current broker version to upgrade to the new version in rolling bounce manner. There might be a possibility that during that process the current consumers reading from old broker has some data left to read which we want to copy to new broker topic so consumers can resume reading from the new broker topic without any data being lost.

Answer (score 1):

If as you say "This will be a one time operation" you can use [kafkacat](https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat) this -o option.

For example (the easiest case):

```
kafkacat -C -b mybrocker_cluster_1:9092 -t mytopic1 -o <offset> | \
kafkacat -P -b mybrocker_cluster_2:9092 -t mytopic1
```

You probably still need to add a few parameters to the consumer:

```
-X message.max.bytes=<value> -X fetch.message.max.bytes=<value> -X receive.message.max.bytes=<value>
```